# How can I add right margins to elements in horizontal bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm well aware that the docs says that I should "*Make sure there is no padding or margins on the ul and li elements*" BUT what if I really need right margin between my slides (li's) ?

I'm opened to switching to another plugin, but it should be able to display html content (not only images) and should be able to be controlled by external calls.

Google was not my friend on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, You should see this [example on BX Slider website](http://www.bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one)

The trick is

```
 $('#slider1').bxSlider({
     displaySlideQty: 3,
     moveSlideQty: 1
 });
```

and give List Element a fix width (you can center inner contents using text-align:center)

in example it looks like:

```
.demo-wrap .multiple li {
     width: 190px;
}
```

Please let me know if it do not work for you. For me it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as it was quite a long time ago, I don't remember why I did not do that, but I think there was a reason...By the way, jCarousel gave me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to ditch bxSlider and use jcarousel instead.
This plugin handles html content and external controls.
Then I was able to define the right margin I needed on *.jcarousel-item-horizontal*.

Everything is now running smoothly.

Not sure about the etiquette, but as I'm quite satisfied with my own answer, I'll mark it as accepted...

EDIT : Imran's answer looks like the best way to go, so I unmark my answer and mark his instead.